# WPF - Checkbox in Datagrid to set background color of row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I'm trying to change the background color of a grid depending on which of two check boxes are checked.  Once I've selected rows in the grid I want to use the data to make an insert to a different table with one field's value being dependent on which of the two check boxes are selected in the grid.  Below is my current code.  I've attempted several thing without success.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TESTWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.507,0.545"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dg"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,81,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Height="214"                   
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="497">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="OK" Width="40">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="OKCCheckBox" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=NONC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RMA ID"
                                Width="80"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=RMA_ID}"
                                />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SERIAL #"
                                Width="80"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=SERIAL_ID}"
                                />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PART #"
                                Width="150"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=INV_ITEM_ID_ORDERED}"
                                />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="QTY"
                                Width="50"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=QTY}"
                                />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NonC" Width="40">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="NONCCheckBox" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=NONC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RMA_ID}" Value="HJRA0000P4">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C# code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace TESTWPF
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataSet GetItemInformationRMAID()
    {
        string _connstring = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=TEST;Password=TEST;";
        string _sql;
        DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            OracleConnection _connObj = new OracleConnection(_connstring);
            _connObj.Open();
            _sql = "select rma_id, serial_id, inv_item_id_ordered, qty from return_line";
            OracleDataAdapter _adapterObj = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(_sql, _connObj);
            _adapterObj.SelectCommand = cmd;
            _adapterObj.Fill(_ds);
            _connObj.Close();
            _connObj.Dispose();
            _connObj = null;
            return _ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return _ds;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg.ItemsSource = GetItemInformationRMAID().Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
}
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but being a newbie I'm just not seeing it.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Why both checkboxes binded to one property Binding Path=NONC ?

Comment: I did notice that copy and past error.  The binding path has been changed to NONC and OK.  Still doesn't work though.